# How to set up _GET in arrays

Tags: php

```
$data2 = [
    'a' => '(!isset($_GET["a"])) ? "default" : htmlspecialchars($_GET["a"]);',
    'b' => '-(!isset($_GET["b"])) ? "default" : htmlspecialchars($_GET["b"]);',
    'c' => '(!isset($_GET["c"])) ? "default" : htmlspecialchars($_GET["c"]);',
    'd' => '(!isset($_GET["d"])) ? "default" : htmlspecialchars($_GET["d"]);',
];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "post request url");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data2));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$x = curl_exec($ch);
echo $x;
```

i use this in a php that calls a POST url with the following request how would i go about setting it up so i can edit 1 php for all like put the file.php?a=28.29.29&b=1232.231.121&c=2121&d=8282832 and it will fill out the post request spots for me any advice would be great

here is how it normally looks manually

```
$data2 = [
    'a' => '228.29.29',
    'b' => '-1232.231.121',
    'c' => '2121',
    'd' => '8282832',

];
```

Comment: Why are you quoting PHP functions (and strings in single quotes)? Those won't execute they'll be strings.

Comment: You should not use `htmlspecialchars()` to encode a URL. The function you're looking for is `urlencode()`, however `http_build_query()` already encodes the query data, so neither are necessary. Just put the plain values into `http_build_query()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your question seems like there is syntax error, please replace $data with below code and it should be working fine.

```
$data2 = [
'a' => (!isset($_GET["a"])) ? "default" : htmlspecialchars($_GET["a"]),
'b' => (!isset($_GET["b"])) ? "default" : "-" .htmlspecialchars($_GET["b"]),
'c' => (!isset($_GET["c"])) ? "default" : htmlspecialchars($_GET["c"]),
'd' => (!isset($_GET["d"])) ? "default" : htmlspecialchars($_GET["d"]),
 ];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "post request url");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data2));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$x = curl_exec($ch);
echo $x;
```

Comment: b needs a - tho so its -whateverafter &b=

Comment: @johnsmith thanks please mark answer right and do upvote, so in future any other user face same difficulty then he/she will know that this answer is correct.

Comment: done do you know anything about removing extra slashes? like the output is {"success":true,"url":"https:\/\/url.com\/file\/565 instead of https://url.com/file/565

Comment: response is in JSON format you can try `$res = json_decode($response, true);` and check $res data it will be perfect :)

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data2));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$x = curl_exec($ch);
$res = json_decode($response, true);
echo $res` ?

Comment: that returns a white page

Comment: Now all the page says is "Array"

Comment: response is in JSON format you can try `$res = json_decode($res, true);` and check $res data it will be perfect :)

Comment: all it returns when i do that is the word "Array" on a white page

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data2));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$x = curl_exec($ch);
$res = json_decode($x, true);
echo $res;

Comment: I'm not sure if still case you can ask another question, because it's not linked with above question. Thanks